# Конвертация формата Android 10-bit raw в cv::Mat

Tags: android, c++, opencv, видео, ffmpeg

Есть формат [RAW10](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#RAW10). Необходимо его конвертировать в `cv::Mat` чтобы в дальнейшем сохранять на диск в контейнер `png/jpeg`.

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
void SaveToDisk(unsigned char * buffer, unsigned int width, unsigned int height) {
        cv::Mat img;
        cv::Mat raw(height, width, CV_8UC1, buffer);
        raw.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1, 255.0); // -> не выходит

        //cv::cvtColor(raw, raw, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB); -> так тоже не выходит
        cv::imwrite("myimage.png", img);
}
```

На выходе получаю серый квадрат.

Еще есть данные о фрейме:
`unsigned int size` и `unsigned int stride`

**UPD:**

Цель не сохранять в заданный контейнер. В контейнер сохраняю, чтобы убедиться в корректности конвертации

Comment: Важно делать это через cv::Mat.

Comment: в данном случае представлен упращенный промежуточный код. Смысл сырые данные преобразовать в мат. Чтобы в дальнейшем после ряда манипуляций сохранять на диск. В данном примере на диск я сохраняю не потому что это цель, а чтобы убедиться в корректности конвертации данных